# Custom InfoWindow for google maps - Unable to set y position

Tags: swift, swift4.2

[image]I am working in Google maps for my project. I need to show image with title in InfoWindow. For that I have create new XIB. Now everything works fine except y position of the InfoWindow. I cannot set InfoWindow Y axis properly. Pls help me with this.

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    var markerData : NSDictionary?

    if let data = marker.userData! as? NSDictionary {
        markerData = data
    }

    locationMarker = marker
    infoWindow.removeFromSuperview()
    infoWindow = loadNiB()

    guard let location = locationMarker?.position else {
        print("locationMarker is nil")
        return false
    }

    infoWindow.spotData = markerData
    infoWindow.alpha = 0.9
    infoWindow.layer.cornerRadius = 12

    let name = markerData!["name"]!
    let imageUrl = markerData!["img"]!

    infoWindow.name.text = "\(name)"

    let trimmedUrl = (imageUrl as AnyObject).trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "")).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")

    var activityLoader = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    activityLoader = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
    activityLoader.center = infoWindow.imgMarker.center
    activityLoader.startAnimating()
    infoWindow.imgMarker.addSubview(activityLoader)

    infoWindow.imgMarker.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: trimmedUrl), completed: { (image, error, imageCacheType, imageUrl) in

        if image != nil
        {
            activityLoader.stopAnimating()
        }
        else
        {
            print("image not found")
            activityLoader.stopAnimating()
        }
    })

    // Offset the info window to be directly above the tapped marker
    infoWindow.center = mapView.projection.point(for: location)
    infoWindow.center.y = infoWindow.center.y - 82
    self.view.addSubview(infoWindow)
    return false
}
```

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your current output.

Comment: Hi I have added image of my map.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the custom marker set the below property :

```
marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.8)
```

Change the value of `y` according to your requirements.

From the screenshot it seems that you need to increase the `y` value like as below :

```
infoWindow.center.y = infoWindow.center.y - 52
```

Follow this link for reference :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to change the position dynamically when click the marker.

Comment: Use 'GMSMapViewDelegate' methods. When the marker is clicked 'mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool' method is called.

Comment: Can you please see the code once again. This is the didTap marker delegate. my problem is I cannot convert the coordinations to infoWindow y axis.

Comment: You just need to update the y value. Updated the answer.